# How Android HTTP cache is working?

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I been investigating [Picaso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), image downloading and caching library for Android. And I found out that their caching mechanism is based on Android [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html). The documentation says:

> To measure cache effectiveness, this class tracks three statistics:
>
> - Request Count: the number of HTTP requests issued since this cache    was created.
> - Network Count: the number of those requests that    required network use.
> - Hit Count: the number of those requests whose    responses were served by the cache.

So how exactly Android Http cache is working?

- How Android knows to cache or not to cache a file, and for how long?
- When exactly the cache is been cleaned, and by who?
- How can I override the default http caching mechanism with my own? And should I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answers are below.

**1) How Android knows to cache or not to cache a file, and for how long?**

The `HttpResponseCache` caches an HTTP or HTTPS response if all of the following is true

- It was installed via `HttpResponseCache.install()`
- `setUseCaches(true)`was called on the `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpsURLConnection`
- The headers returned by the HTTP/HTTPS server allow caching. See the `ResponseHeaders.isCacheable()` [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/android-4.4.4_r1/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/ResponseHeaders.java) for the nitty-gritty details.

The cache uses a LRU strategy replacing older cached responses with newer ones to make sure it does not exceed the allotted disk size.

**2) When exactly the cache is been cleaned, and by who?**

If the cache is initialized with a directory in `Context.getCacheDir()` or `Context.getExternalCacheDir()` then the files are usually deleted when the app is uninstalled. The cache can be deleted manually by calling `HttpResponseCache.delete()`

**3) How can I override the default http caching mechanism with my own? And should I?**

See `HttpResponseCache.install()`. If your app loads of cacheable resources via HTTP or HTTPS and does not have its own caching layer then you should consider using it. The Android default `HttpResponseCache` implementation should work fine.

Please note that by default no cache is used. You need to install one with `HttpResponseCache.install()`.

Comment: And Picasso sets the default cache here https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/UrlConnectionDownloader.java#L96

Comment: Actually [HttpResponseCache.install](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html#install%28java.io.File,%20long%29) says nothing about how to "override the default http caching mechanism" (3). Or were you pointing to the source? Instead I would point to [ResponseCache.setDefault](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ResponseCache.html#setDefault%28java.net.ResponseCache%29).

Comment: How can I obtain value of ETag from cache?